# pre populate input in form angular

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a component with a form that has some inputs with data validations
How can I pre populate with the logged user's info?

**userService.ts**

```
public getCurrentUser():User {
  return this.currentUser;
}
```

**component.ts**

```
vendorInformationForm: FormGroup;
states = states;

constructor(
  private fb: FormBuilder,
  private userService: UserService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.initForm();
}

initForm() {
  this.vendorInformationForm = this.fb.group({
    name: [null],
    adress: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(60)]],
    city: ['', Validators.maxLength(20)],
    state: ['', [Validators.required]],
    zip: ['', [Validators.required]],
    vendorNumber: [null],
    minimumOrderAmount: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0) ,Validators.pattern('^[0-9]$')]],
    freightPrepaidAt: ['', [Validators.required]],
    preferredShipper: ['', [Validators.required]],
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
  })
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="adress">Adress</label>
            <input type="text" id="adress" class="form-control" formControllName="adress"> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

... and so on for every field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When initializing your form with `this.fb.group` you can pass default data to your form inputs :

```
User user = this.getUser()
    this.vendorInformationForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [this.user.name ? this.user.name : ''],
      adress: [this.user.address ? this.user.address : '', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(60)]],
      email: [this.user.email ? this.user.email : '', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      ...
    })
```

If you want to update theses data after the initialization of the form, you can use the `patchValue` method :

```
this.vendorInformationForm.patchValue('yourinputname', 'thenewvalue')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
this.form.setValue({
  name: [response.name],
  adress: [response.address]
});
```

Replace accordingly to your response

Answer (score 1):

We can use `setValue()` or `patchValue()` to set data

Try like this:

```
let vendorData = {
   name : "Adrita",
   ...
}

this.vendorInformationForm.patchValue(vendorData)
```

If you have all the information, then use `setValue` otherwise use `patchValue`

Answer (score 1):

What properties do the user have? In general you have the possibility to use the form-groups `patchValue` or `setValue` function

```js
this.vendorInformationForm.patchValue(this.userService.getCurrentUser());
```

or

```
this.vendorInformationForm.setValue(this.userService.getCurrentUser());
```

The `patchValue` patches all fields that are matching between the values and the form configuration. The `setValue` function requires the data to be exactly of the formgroups form.

Answer (score 1):

To update your form you can do it using the methods patchValue() or setValue().  This way:

**component.ts**

```js
   const userInfo =  this.userService.getCurrentUser();

   this.vendorInformationForm.patchValue(userInfo);
```